# Can I use K-means algorithm on a string?

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, k-means

I am working on a python project where I study RNA structure evolution (represented as a string for example: "(((...)))" where the parenthesis represent basepairs). The point being is that I have an ideal structure and a population that evolves towards the ideal structure. I have implemented everything however I would like to add a feature where I can get the "number of buckets" ie the k most representative structures in the population at each generation.

I was thinking of using the k-means algorithm but I am not sure how to use it with strings. I found [scipy.cluster.vq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html) but I don't know how to use it in my case.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K-means doesn't really care about the type of the data involved. All you need to do a K-means is some way to measure a "distance" from one item to another. It'll do its thing based on the distances, regardless of how that happens to be computed from the underlying data.

That said, I haven't used `scipy.cluster.vq`, so I'm not sure exactly how you tell it the relationship between items, or how to compute a distance from item A to item B.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. What is the "distance" between two strings of RNA such that it A) obeys the triangle inequality and B) is euclidean? There are many clustering algorithms, and it seems beyond me how k-means in particular would be useful in this circumstance.

Comment: The distance I am using is the structural distance, for example sequences:
(1) "(((....)))" and
(2) "((((..))))"

Have a distance of 1 since the only difference in an insertion

Comment: Jerry, can you please explain how this can possibly work? As @sclv mentioned in his answer, K-means only works with Euclidean distance. It seems impossible to apply it to strings since at each step, you need to shift the centroids to an absolute position representing the mean of the closest data points... For arbitrary distance metrics, it seems that [**K-medoids**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) would work instead since it uses data points as centroids  instead.

Comment: @codesparkle: I didn't try to tell him that his measure of distance would work--I simply pointed out (at least part of) the requirement for K-means to work. There definitely are measures of differences between strings that fit those requirements (e.g., cosine similarity). Oh, and sclv's claim isn't entirely correct either: cosine similarity isn't strictly a Euclidean measure, but does just fine. Multiple definitions of centroid are accepted wrt k-means (e.g., [3](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~han/dmclass/cluster_survey_10_02_00.pdf)), with differing requirements on the measure used.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. K-means also needs to compute *means*, and that requires floats, and requires squared Euclidean or Bergman divergences as "distance".

Comment: Anything that's a "metric" will work, and a few things like Bregman divergence (which is what I'd guess you were trying to refer to) will work even though they're not actually metrics. Metrics most assuredly are *not* restricted to Euclidean distance though.

Comment: No, metrics will not work. They may not converge. That is why PAM exists, to make other metrics work. k-means uses the mean, and the mean is *not* the center for every metric.

Answer (score 14):

One problem you would face if using `scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans` is that that function uses Euclidean distance to measure closeness. To shoe-horn your problem into one solveable by `k-means` clustering, you'd have to find a way to convert your strings into numerical vectors and be able to justify using Euclidean distance as a reasonable measure of closeness.

That seems... difficult. Perhaps you are looking for [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance#DNA) instead?

Note there are [variants of the K-means algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12495/842) that can work with non-Euclideance distance metrics (such as Levenshtein distance). `K-medoids` (aka PAM), for instance, [can be applied to data with an arbitrary distance metric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81496/842).

For example, using [`Pycluster`'s](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm) implementation of `k-medoids`, and [`nltk`'s](http://www.nltk.org/) implementation of Levenshtein distance,

```
import nltk.metrics.distance as distance
import Pycluster as PC

words = ['apple', 'Doppler', 'applaud', 'append', 'barker', 
         'baker', 'bismark', 'park', 'stake', 'steak', 'teak', 'sleek']

dist = [distance.edit_distance(words[i], words[j]) 
        for i in range(1, len(words))
        for j in range(0, i)]

labels, error, nfound = PC.kmedoids(dist, nclusters=3)
cluster = dict()
for word, label in zip(words, labels):
    cluster.setdefault(label, []).append(word)
for label, grp in cluster.items():
    print(grp)
```

yields a result like

```
['apple', 'Doppler', 'applaud', 'append']
['stake', 'steak', 'teak', 'sleek']
['barker', 'baker', 'bismark', 'park']
```

Answer (score 10):

K-means only works with euclidean distance. Edit distances such as Levenshtein don't <strike>even obey the triangle inequality</strike> may obey the triangle inequality, but are not euclidian. For the sorts of metrics you're interested in, you're better off using a different sort of algorithm, such as Hierarchical clustering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering

Alternately, just convert your list of RNA into a weighted graph, with Levenshtein weights at the edges, and then decompose it into a minimum spanning tree. The most connected nodes of that tree will be, in a sense, the "most representative".

Comment: [Levenshtein Distance and the Triangle Inequality](http://richardminerich.com/2012/09/levenshtein-distance-and-the-triangle-inequality/)

Comment: Thanks, fixed! Embarrassingly, the author of the blog is a friend of mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you need for Kmeans is a 'distance' measure (numbers representing a vector so it can find the distances between the vectors and cluster them around centroids based on the distances).  Following are some examples I wrote for you:

- Let's say you've got strings that represent dates like `2019-06-27
  15:52:41.623Z`.  What you want to do in this case is pick a date say when UTC timestamps start.  Now with that starting date and time as the reference, you can calculate the 'distance' to each date string.
- Suppose instead, you have code strings, `if(a == b)` vs. `if(a == c)`
  then you might want to use a different 'distance' like the number of
  characters that differ between the strings.
- Or if you have Html DOM structure, `<html></html>` vs
  `<html><head></head></html>` you might not want to count characters
  but how many tags are different as your 'distance'.
- Or for a known enum in database, you could define each key as a different number with your own idea of 'distance' between the enums.  For example, 'male', 'female', 'neutral' if you define as the vectors [0], [1], [2] would imply neutral is closer to female than male.  So you might instead want to do [0],[2],[1] or [-1],[1],[0].
- For RNA/DNA structure asked in the question, the 'distance' could be
  how many base pairs are different between the strands.

I hope you get the idea.  So, you need to consider what is the content of your string and think of the best way to define the 'distance' between your content.  Simple character diff distance could work as a generic distance measure between strings, but if you get better distance ideas, your algorithm will work better.