# Recommender Systems Datasets

Tags: algorithm, matlab, dataset

i have a fully dataset for a recommender system i need to built in matlab.

I import all the dataset into MATLAB as a cell array.

I now need to add values to words and apply the k modes algorithm.

How i can do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should first check matlab documentation

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html

EDIT:
Also check [Levenshtein_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [Jaccard Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

Comment: i have tried these but my dataset is text, kmeans only works with number as it finds distances.

Comment: You need to define a way to measure distance between strings
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6293637/730313  

You can also check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index   
Another popular way is by Levenshtein distance